# LINQ result on datatable without for loop

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I am sure this is easy (or that I am completely wrong), but all I want to do is get the single values against a LINQ query on a datatable and not use a for.. each loop to access them.

Scenario..
I have a datatable containing a number of rows. I run my query looking for a particular match on "EP" like such..

`Dim qryB = From rw In oDT_Cables
Where rw("EP").Equals(br.Position)
Select ld = rw("LOAD"), tl = rw("TOT-LEN")`

Now..
I know that I have only one result (due to checking upon insertion), so how do I simply access the items ld and tl without a for each loop??

I have tried:

```
qryb.elementat(1)   error
qryb.elementat(ld)  Not possible
qryb.tl             not possible
```

Does anyone know how I can access tl and ld from the query please? It is much appreciated.

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for a fact that a LINQ query produces a single result then you call `Single`.

```
Dim result = qryB.Single()
```

If there may be no result but will never be more than one then you call `SingleOrDefault` and the result may be `Nothing`.  If there will be at least one result but may be more and you want just the first, you call `First`.  If there may be zero, one or more and you want the first if there is one then you call `FirstOrDefault` and the result may be `Nothing`.

Note that some LINQ providers don't support both options, e.g. LINQ to Entities (the LINQ provider for Entity Framework) supports `First` and `FirstOrDefault` but not `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` (unless it's changed recently) while, if I'm not mistaken, LINQ to SQL supports `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` but not `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Note that, if you were going to use `ElementAt`, you would have to specify 0 as the index.  `ElementAt` works pretty much like indexing a array or other `IList`, so the first item is at index 0.  You'd only use `ElementAt` for something in the middle of a query result though, given that you have `Single`, `First` and `Last` methods and their nullable equivalents.

Comment: I had to read this a few times, but finally your comment about the index being 0 is what clicked it. For anyone else who ever comes here, my answer was to use qryb.elementat(0).ld

Comment: It seems like my answer didn't really sink in if you're still using `ElementAt`. If you know for a fact that there will be one result, why would you use `ElementAt(0)` instead of `Single`?

Comment: It sunk in and I did use the first etc, but I had already written Elementat(0). I am honestly thankful, but I guess I have failed to understand if there is really a difference between using the 0 index or first or single? Technically, do they not all give me the same value equally? Thanks again but.